# How to detect login window close event on LinkedIn Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I am using LinkedIn Javascript SDK to log my users in, and I need to detect if a user closes the login/auth window before they complete the login or authorization. Current SDK doesn't fire the login callback when the window is closed (I naturally expect it to be called with `IN.User.isAuthorized()` set to `false` just like in Facebook Javascript SDK).

How can I detect when the user closes the Login with LinkedIn window?

Answer (score 2):

The LinkedIn API is a bit of a nightmare to deal with.

I had a similar issue where it was firing multiple requests if they opened the auth window more than once. I solved this by adding a count each time they opened the window and then ignoring everything if `count > 1`. My solution involves Angular and Promises so I'm not going to post the full *solution*.

For you, I would just add `authTriggered` and `authComplete` variables. The triggered gets set when they click they link/button to authorise with LinkedIn and the complete variable gets set in the auth callback.

Something like this perhaps?

```
var LinkedIn = LinkedIn || {};

LinkedIn = {
  authTriggered: false,
  authComplete: false,
  authorise: function() {
    IN.User.authorize(function() {
      this.authComplete = true;
    });
  }
};

var authLink = document.getElementById('auth-link');
authLink.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  LinkedIn.authTriggered = true;

  LinkedIn.authorise();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jem, I'll be trying this ASAP.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu I hope it helps. If you have any questions then please let me know. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `IN.User.authorize()` please use `IN.UI.Authorize()` as

```
var linkedin = IN.UI.Authorize().place();
linkedin.onWindowRemove.subscribe(function() {
// perform some action
});
```

thanks sanju for this answer
https://sanjutalks.wordpress.com/2017/10/04/linkedin-javascript-sdk-detecting-login-windows-close-event/